# A question regarding $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$ and Apostol's Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise 7.19 of Tom Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* defines $$f(x) = \left(\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt\right)^2,\;\; g(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt $$ and asks to prove that $f'(x) + g'(x) = 0$ and, from that, $f(x)+g(x)=\pi/4$.

I've successfully proven that $f'(x) + g'(x) = 0$:

$$f'(x) = 2e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$$

$$g'(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{e^{-x^2(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}\right)dt = -2e^{-x^2}\int xe^{-t^2x^2}dt$$ Making $u=xt$, $du = xdt$, $$g'(x) = -2e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{-u^2}du$$ And, with this, $f'(x) + g'(x) = 0$. But how, from this, should I get to the second claim?, **any tips**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $x=0$ and that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t^2+1} = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

Comment: With this one can easily prove that $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt = \sqrt{\pi}/2$. My argument would go as follows: on $f(x) + g(x) = \pi/4$, consider $x\to\infty$, because $g(x) \to 0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt)^2 = \pi/4$, thus the claim. Do you think this reasoning is correct? (And, of course, many thanks)

Comment: @Miguelgondu: I completely agree.

Answer (score 2):

Because $\frac{d}{dx}(f+g)=0$, we know that $f+g$ is a constant, so we need only to plug in a number. For instance $x=0$.

$f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Brilliant, hadn't thought about it. Just like solving a PVI, am I right?

Comment: @Miguelgondu That depends on what a PVI is, haha.

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb, I just said the spanish version of IVP (initial value problem), :P.